Approximating counting measure by finite Borel measure on the plane that is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue with positive continuous density
I have been working on understanding the following detail in a proof concerning partitioning the plane via three concurrent lines into six "equally sized sectors". This post is self-contained and I don't think you need any of the context, but if you're interested see either the remark after the statement of Proposition 1 here or page 77 of Bárány's book Combinatorial Convexity.
I will first state the setup and then outline all of my attempts at understanding the detail.
Setup:
Call a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on the plane neat if it is abosolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure and has a positive continuous density. I think this means, by Radon-Nikodym that there exists a positive continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$
$$
\mu(A) = \int_A f dm \quad \text{where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure}.
$$
Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a finite set of points. Define the counting measure $\nu$ of $X$ by
$$
\nu(A) := |A\cap X|.
$$
I am trying to prove that the counting measure can be approximated by neat measures.
My attempts My attempt at this has been as follows: Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with nonempty interior.
Let $r_A$ be small enough so that if $x \in \mathrm{int}(A)$ then $B(x,r_A) \subseteq A$ and if $x \in \mathrm{bd}(A)$ then $m(B(x,r_A) \cap A)$ is close to $\frac12 m(B(x,r_A))$.
Let $1_A$ be the indicator function for $A$. So,
$$
        1_A(x) = \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}.
        \end{cases}
$$
Let $B_A := B(0,r_A)$ be the ball centered at the origin with radius $r_A$.
Define
$$
    g(u) = \frac{1}{m(B_A)}\sum_{x \in X} 1_{B(x,r_A)}(u).
$$
Note that $g(u)$ is $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and hence, since continuous functions are
dense in $L^1$ we get that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a continuous function
$f_\epsilon$ such that
$$
    \int |f_\epsilon - g| ~dm < \epsilon. 
$$
Now define
$$
    \mu_\epsilon(A) := \int_A |f_\epsilon| dm 
$$
Case 1: $X$ doesn't contain points on the boundary of
$A$.
In this case
$B(x,r_A) \subseteq A$ for all $x \in A\cap X$. So
\begin{align*}
    \int_A g(u) ~ dm &= \frac{1}{m(B_A)} \sum_{x \in X} \int_A 1_{B(x,r)}(u) dm \\
    &= \frac{1}{m(B_A)} \sum_{x \in X} m(B(x,r) \cap A) \\
    &= \frac{1}{m(B_A)} \sum_{x \in A\cap X} m(B_A) \\
    &= |A\cap X|.
\end{align*}
My question and concerns are:

is it ok that the radius of the balls depend on the set $A$;
is there a better way to do this or is there a more "standard" way to do this approximation;

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

If such an $r_A>0$ exists, and $A$ has a non empty interior, then $A$ is the entire plane.

Ah I see what you mean. I will keep thinking about how to fix this. Thank you for noticing this.

The problem has well-known solutions for the case $X={(0,0)}$. You can leverage that solution to prove the general case.

Thank you for the comment! I have been thinking about how to solve for the case when $X$ only contains the origin. One thought that was shared with me while talking with a friend was to consider the bump function (normalized properly). Was this the well-known solution you are referring to?
